# SP 2013, Survey App, Show toolbar only

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am creating an online voting option for our Halloween Costumes this year, using the Survey app. I've created a wiki page where I can put both the survey and the picture library together so people can see the pictures and respond to the survey at the same time.

When I add in the app, I only want it to show the tool bar (Respond to this Survey) and nothing else. I don't want the survey name, description etc etc on the bottom. I tried changing views, changing chrome states, etc and I can't seem to hide it.

[image: Survey App]

Any help appreciated, thank you!

** Edit **

I tried the advice given below but I'm not sure what you mean by adding the survey name and such

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add edit snippet web part and add the following code to hide section containing SurveyName, Survey Description, etc.

`<style>
   .ms-summarystandardbody
          display:none;
</style>`

Comment: not sure what you mean, I edited my post to include what I did..